# Interpreting CISC as RISC

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture

I'm preparing for a test in computer science and there's this question that keeps coming up in previous tests that I can't find an answer to.

Consider the execution of the two instructions below on a typical RISC architecture with only one addressing mode (Reg + Offset).

```
804836e:    40            inc    %eax
804836f:    89 04 91      mov    %eax,(%ecx,%edx,4)
```

**Explain**, **justifying**, how these 2 IA-32 instructions would be compiled for this architecture, using IA-32 sintaxe to show that code.

**Comment** on the size of this piece of code on the RISC architecture versus the IA-32.

The C function is :

```
voidpara_par (int a[], int n) {
    int i;
    for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
        if (a[i] & 0x01) {
            a[i] += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Which receives an array of ints and increments the value of the odd ones.

For reference:

```
%eax -> int i
(%ecx,%edx,4) -> int, part of the array "a" saved to %ecx
```

I know this question feels vague to say the least but that's my problem, I don't really know how to begin "translating" from one architecture to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inc eax
mov [ecx+edx*4],eax
```

is pretty much using trivial instructions, so why this is not actual answer also for RISC-like?

Because the constraint is *"only one addressing mode (Reg + Offset)."* (and also it's unlikely the RISC will have `inc`, but that can be "fixed" by simple `add eax,1`).

So you have to convert the addressing from the `base_reg + index_reg*index_size_imm + ofs` x86 addressing mode to `reg + ofs`. If you will think about it for a short while, there's no reasonable way to use the "ofs" part, unless you create self-modifying code, putting some nifty ofs into the instruction opcode before executing it.. so it's narrowed down to task "do it by (reg+0) addressing mode".

And so you do the address math "manually"

```
add  eax,1   ; inc eax
shl  edx,2   ; edx = edx*4
add  ecx,edx ; ecx = ecx + edx*4
mov  [ecx+0],eax
```

Done. (Intel syntax used intentionally, because I don't think the GAS/AT&T is supposed to be used by humans).

---

all the explaining/reasoning about result left to the OP, because he should try. :) (let me know in comment if you get stuck)

---

BTW, if you would translate that whole C part, it would certainly lead to more optimal machine code, without the *4 multiplying in the first place, so both x86 and "RISC" machine code would look lot more similar, except the x86 can manipulate the array element directly in memory:

DANG, I managed to create "increase every element", missed the `if` part, sorry.... not going to fix, as this illustrates the looping vs indexing thing any way, which was my original intention to point out, that the original `mov %eax,(%ecx, %edx, 4)` is quite artificial and would be hardly found in optimized machine code.

```
    eax = array + n*4
    ecx = -n*4
loop:
    inc dword [eax+ecx]
    add ecx,4
    jnz loop
```

RISC-like version:

```
    ebx = array
    ecx = n
loop:
    mov eax,[ebx]
    add eax,1
    mov [ebx],eax
    add ebx,4
    sub ecx,1
    jnz loop
```

Again no index needed, that's high level stuff, which can be usually easily avoided in optimized machine code, with enough fixed constraints about data structure, like here each element is of fixed 4-byte size.

Answer (score 4):

The question just wants you to realize that the read-modify-write (RMW) instructions that exist in the x86 instruction set (a classically "CISC" [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture)) would not be available on a RISC instruction set. Neither would the complex memory addressing that you find in x86 instructions.

Instead, a classic RISC ISA would provide only a "simplified" set of instructions, meaning that you'd have to decompose the x86 CISC-style instructions into a set of simpler instructions. In other words, you just break them up into their component bits.

Beyond showing you the classic contrast between CISC and RISC, the other reason why this is a somewhat interesting exercise is because it's the same thing that a modern x86 processor is doing internally. You see, even though you (the programmer) write this CISC-style code for x86, internally, the processor is actually more like a RISC system, so when it decodes the instruction, it decodes it into a series of µops that resemble what a programmer would write for a RISC system.

Let's study the instructions you were given:

```
804836e:    40            inc    %eax
804836f:    89 04 91      mov    %eax,(%ecx,%edx,4)
```

The parameter (an `int`) was passed in the `EAX` register, so this just increments it by 1. Most likely, on a RISC system, there would not be specialized `INC` and `DEC` instructions like there are on x86. These were added to x86 to mirror the `++i` and `--i` statements in languages like C, but notice that they are equivalent to an addition (or subtraction) of 1. So, on a RISC system, you would just write:

```
add  $1, %eax
```

Then the `MOV` instruction. This one's a doozie. First, we need to figure out what it's actually doing. In this AT&T/GAS syntax, it's very difficult to see what is happening (in my opinion), so let's rewrite it into the more normal Intel/MASM syntax:

```
mov  DWORD PTR [ecx+edx*4], eax
```

Now, it is clear that this scales (multiplies) the contents of the `EDX` register by 4, adds this to the contents of the `ECX` register, and then stores the contents of `EAX` at this address.

A classic RISC system would not support this complex memory addressing, so we need to break it down into simpler bits. That's not hard, though, now that we understand what the instruction is doing:

```
shl  edx, 2                  ; edx *= 4
add  edx, ecx                ; edx += ecx
mov  DWORD PTR [edx], eax    ; store EAX at address in EDX
```

It's also worth noting that a classic RISC system wouldn't overload the `MOV` instruction like x86 does. Typically, RISC is a [load-store architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load/store_architecture), which would break the x86's `MOV` instruction into three different things:

- A register-to-register `MOV` instruction
- A `LOAD` instruction to load from memory into a register
- A `STORE` instruction to store from a register into memory

So if you were actually translating this to a RISC ISA, the code might look more like:

```
shl    edx, 2
add    edx, ecx
store  [edx], eax
```

Not a big difference, but important to understand that on a normal RISC system, `MOV` wouldn't do all things like it does on x86.

Another minor thing, if you're the type that likes to nitpick. The complex memory addressing that we were originally using in the x86 `MOV` instruction doesn't actually modify the `ECX` or `EDX` registers, whereas our "translated" version clobbers the `EDX` register. If we wanted to be precise, we would need to:

```
mov    reg9, edx    ; a reg-reg move to a new temporary register
shl    reg9, 2
add    reg9, ecx
store  [reg9], eax
```

where `reg9` is a new temporary register. In modern implementations of x86, this would be a hidden, *non-architectural* register, which just means it's one that the processor's hardware has but is not exposed to the programmer as part of the instruction set. On most RISC systems, this wouldn't be necessary either, because their instructions accept *three* operands (operand 1, operand 2, and destination), so that the result can be placed in a different register without clobbering any of the operands. Thus, you'd have:

```
shl   reg9, edx, 2
add   reg9, reg9, ecx
store [reg9], eax
```

So, putting it all together in AT&T syntax, the desired answer would be something like:

```
add    $1, %eax         # increment EAX by 1
mov    %edx, %reg9      # reg-reg move of EDX to a temp
shl    $2, %reg9        # scale by 4
add    %ecx, %reg9      # add offset in ECX
store  %eax, (%reg9)    # store EAX at this address
```

---

Just for fun, let's take the C code that you were given and see how it would look when compiled for the two different types of architectures. Here is what GCC 4.8 generates when targeting x86 (a classic CISC architecture):

```
para_par(int*, int):
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [esp+8]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+4]
        test    edx, edx
        lea     ecx, [eax+edx*4]
        jle     .L1
.L5:
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [eax]
        test    dl, 1
        je      .L3
        inc     edx
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax], edx
.L3:
        add     eax, 4
        cmp     eax, ecx
        jne     .L5
.L1:
        ret
```

Now, rewriting this to RISC style (as your assignment calls for) would be pretty simple—there aren't that many "complex" instructions there, other than that `LEA`. I might do something like:

```
para_par(int*, int):
        load    ecx, DWORD PTR [esp+8]
        cmp     ecx, 0
        jle     .L1
        load    eax, DWORD PTR [esp+4]
        add     ecx, ecx
        add     ecx, ecx
        add     ecx, eax
.L5:
        load    edx, DWORD PTR [eax]
        test    dl, 1    ; a bit "complex" because it's an AND that doesn't modify, but
                         ; on RISC, we'd have the three-operand form of AND to avoid modifying
        je      .L3
        add     edx, 1
        store   DWORD PTR [eax], edx
.L3:
        add     eax, 4
        cmp     eax, ecx
        jne     .L5
.L1:
        ret
```

Here's what GCC 4.8 generates if you compile for PowerPC (a classic RISC architecture):

```
para_par(int*, int):
        cmpwi 7,4,0       # compare to 0
        addi 3,3,-4       # add
        slwi 4,4,2        # left-shift by 2
        add 4,3,4         # add
        blelr- 7          # branch if less-than-or-equal
        subf 4,3,4        # subtract
        addi 4,4,-4       # add
        srwi 4,4,2        # right-shift by 2
        addi 4,4,1        # add
        mtctr 4           # move to count register (a special register)
.L9:
        lwzu 9,4(3)       # load from memory
        andi. 10,9,1      # bitwise AND
        addi 9,9,1        # add
        beq- 0,.L3        # branch if equal-to
        stw 9,0(3)        # store to memory
.L3:
        bdnz .L9          # decrement and branch if not-zero
        blr               # unconditional branch (JMP)
```

Of course, the mnemonics for PowerPC are all different from those for x86, which makes understanding it difficult if you've only ever studied x86. You can look up the mnemonics, but even without going through that much effort, you can still pick out a lot of what I've mentioned—the "simpler" instructions, the separate loads (`lwzu`) and stores (`stw`), and the *three* operands instead of two.

Curiously, both because of the code that was selected as the example and because of the magic of an optimizing compiler, there isn't that much difference between the x86 ("CISC") disassembly and the PowerPC ("RISC") disassembly.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to spend enough time on my answer, this is lot more complete. Just for fun fact: `add x,1` vs `inc x` on x86 is even more tricky, as the `inc` does *not* update carry flag, which can be rarely exploited in certain algorithms, like doing addition over multiple elements of array with carry, and counting number of elements by `dec` (preserving carry for addition itself). Some RISC CPUs make up for this by having the ++/-- modifiers for the load/store instructions (similar to x86 lods/stos, but more powerful)... Any way, most of the ISAs tend to have some interesting details :)